# setting all elements of a numpy array to zero vs. creating a new array of zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing a bunch of linear algebra on large matrices over and over millions of times in a while loop using numpy, at the beginning of each iteration I need the arrays to be all zeros.

Is it most efficient to reuse the existing arrays by setting all the elements to zero, ie: `array[:, :, :] = 0` or to create a new array of all zeros, ie: `array = np.zeros((a, b, c))`

I would think that setting the elements to zero is best, but I don't know.

Comment: Are you going to fill all the cells on this new array?

Comment: @mozway no not necessarily, in some cases yes and not in other cases, but I can't have garbage values in the cells that I don't set. An important point though is that if cell `array[:, i, j]` is not set in one iteration then it wont be in the other iterations either. But I do need all cells to start out as zero at the beginning of each iteration, otherwise of course I could just override the old values in each iteration.

Comment: I asked because you could have left the array untouched or used `np.empty`, but this won't work if you don't fill all.

Comment: I compared both, the new array is much faster (see full answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a new array seems 1000 times faster on 10M cells

#### new array

```
%%timeit
a = np.zeros((1000,10000))
```

Output:

```
20.2 µs ± 1.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#### filling existing array

```
%%timeit
a[:,:] = 0
```

Output:

```
19.4 ms ± 1.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Huh, that's very surprising to me, are you sure it doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you are not populating the arrays at all??

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I guess what I mean is are you sure numpy ever actually allocates the array of zeroes in the case where you are just creating arrays of zeros over and over again, and that there isn't some other quirky detail that makes this an artifact of the way you are testing it?. I'm not discrediting your answer I'm just being a bit critical of the result because it seems strange to me..

Comment: Quite sure yes, I tried different approaches (loops, unique large array...) and I get at least a factor 100. But the best might be to give it a try in your real use case ;)

Comment: I wonder why this is the case, my thinking is that when allocating an array of zeros numpy needs to go through a space in the memory and fill it with all zeros, seems like it would be the same as setting an existing array to all zeros except the need to allocate new space..

Comment: This is because `np.zeros` does not actually populate the array. It calls `calloc` (if possible: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L812-L821), which reserves pages in virtual memory to represent the array of zeros, and then actually allocates real memory the first time it is written to. Compare the time of `np.empty` (14.1 µs), `np.zeros` (11.5 µs), and `np.ones` (843 ms) on a billion floats. `np.empty` and `np.zeros` are both only reserving virtual memory, but `np.ones` is doing the much more time-consuming task of actually filling them with data.